# What is the best way to save query results with a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view, phpmyadmin

I want to show all the pairs of similar products liked together by users so I thought of creating a VIEW in order to update the table dynamically.

I get the message that I can not CREATE A VIEW with a subquery.
I also thought of creating a temporary table but it's not effective.

How can I save my query results in a table when there is a VIEW limitation?

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.item1
           , c.item2
           , count(*) as times_liked_together 
         FROM 
     ( SELECT a.product_id as item1
            , b.product_id as item2 
    FROM items a 
    join items b 
         ON a.wishlist_id = b.wishlist_id 
         AND a.product_id != b.product_id
     ) c 
 GROUP 
      BY c.item1
     , c.item2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has this limitation on views.  In your case, you don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT i1.product_id as item1, i2.product_id as liked_with,
       COUNT(*) as num_liked_together
FROM items i1 INNER JOIN
     items i2
     ON i1.wishlist_id = i2.wishlist_id AND
        i1.product_id < i2.product_id
GROUP BY item1, item2;
```

Note that I changed the `<>` to `<`.  I don't see a reason to have both (a, b) and (b, a) in the result set.  If you do, change the `<` back to `<>`.

Also, `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never used with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you so much.:) I was struggling with it for a long time.